# git is injecting text in html

Tags: git, github

after i made a pull in my server i noticed that there is some weird text on my html .

some files on my server were changed so i had to merge the branch.

[image: Screenshot]

the text is showing in my Vue component in my home page.

i recompiled the code many time to check if it was the component but its not going off.

I don't understand where it came from ?

I tried to undo the commit.But it changed nothing .

any idea what's going on here?

Comment: It is a merge conflict. 

Have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git

Comment: Someone (probably you) lied to Git that they resolved a merge conflict when they in fact did not.

Comment: @UtsavPatel the problem was solved. it turns out there is a merge conflict like Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica said . thanks